# Attach click listener to a class to toggle visibility of all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click "title text", the `<ol>` element does not hide, *and it should*. I've checked the jquery documentation (and searched SO) on .click() .children() .toggle() and .hide(), and I cannot find anything I've done wrong. I am working in the http://codepen.io environment.

My HTML

```
<p class="hidable">title text
  <ol>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ol>
</p>
```

My JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hidable').click(function() {
    $(this).children().toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A paragraph can only contain inline elements.

Where your `<ol>` is a block element, when your browser renders your code, it places a paragraph either side of your ordered list, the ordered list is not a child of the paragraph:

[image]

How about having the list follow the paragraph:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hidable').click(function () {
        $(this).next('ol').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="hidable">title text</p>
<ol>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Ah! I did not know that. I often forget the significance of inline vs block elements. It makes sense, and I was able to get my code working. Thank you!